# call non-static methods without creating an object in the same class in Java

Tags: java

I understood that if I need to call `getItemList` ouside the class without an object, I need to make the method public and static. What I am confused about is the case inside the class.

In the following code, can I call `getItemList` method without creating a `GitHubClient` object? If I want to call `getItemList` method directly, should I make the method static?

```
public class GitHubClient {
  private String s1 = "abc"

  public List<Item> search(double lat, double lon, String keyword) {
    // omit code using GitHub client to request info
    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseBody);
    // can I call the method without an object
    return getItemList(array);
  }

  private List<Item> getItemList(JSONArray array) {
    // helper function to filter the search result
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to be able to call `getItemList(JSONArray)` from outside of `GithubClient` without creating an object, you'll have to make it both `public` and `static`.

Basically, `public static List<Item> getItemList(JSONArray array) {...}`

Comment: If I want to call `getItemList` inside the `GitHubClient` class, do I need to create an object if the method is non-static?

Comment: Nope, you can just call it as `GithubClient.getItemList(...)` there too. Prefer the static call over just `getItemList(...)` in that case. :-)

Comment: A  non-static method **must** be called on an instance of the object.  Because that's what they're for.  There are two divisions of methods, ones that belong to a particular object and ones that do not. The latter are called "static".   You're asking for static behavior but on something that isn't static - it's contradictory.